# Java Check Mail Lab

Tags: java, if-statement, programming-languages, java.util.scanner, system.out

For some reason my code keeps coming out with all zeros:
Here is what I am supposed to do:
LAB ASSIGNMENT A8.1
Check Mail

The U.S. post office has rules about mailing packages. A package cannot be mailed first class if the

sum of its length and girth is greater than 100 inches, or if the package weighs more than 70 pounds.

The girth is the perimeter around the height and width, where the length is defined as the longest of

Write a program that takes in the weight of the package and the three dimensions of the package in

any order. The program should determine the longest dimension of the package, calculate the girth,

and compute the size of the box. The program should then print out one of the following messages

1. Package is too large and too heavy.
2. Package is too large.
3. Package is too heavy.
4. Package is acceptable.

Here is the code that I have done:
      //Driver Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CheckMailDriver {
    static int myHeight;
    static int myLength;
    static int myWidth;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Dimension 1. ");
    int d1=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Dimension 2. ");
    int d2=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Dimension 3. ");
    int d3=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the weight of the package. ");
    int weight=input.nextInt();
    if ((d1>d2)&&(d1>d3)){
        d1=myLength;
        d2=myHeight;
        d3=myWidth;
    }
    else
        if ((d2>d1)&&(d2>d3)){
            d2=myLength;
            d1=myHeight;
            d3=myWidth;
        }
    else
        if ((d3>d1)&&(d3>d2)){
                d3=myLength;
                d1=myHeight;
                d2=myWidth;
            }
    CheckMail mail=new CheckMail(myLength,myHeight,myWidth,weight);
    System.out.println("The length of the package is "+myLength);
    System.out.println("The height of the package is "+myHeight);
    System.out.println("The width of the package is "+myWidth);
    mail.calculateGirth();
    mail.calculateValid();
    input.close();


}
```

}
     //Class Code

```
public class CheckMail {
    int myHeight;
    int myLength;
    int myWidth;
    int myWeight;
    int mygirth;

public CheckMail(int d1, int d2, int d3, int wt){
    d1=myLength;
    d2=myHeight;
    d3=myWidth;
    wt=myWeight;



}

public void calculateGirth(){
    int mygirth=(2*myHeight)+(2*myWidth);
    System.out.println("The girth of the package is "+mygirth);

}
public void calculateValid(){
    if ((mygirth+myLength>=100)&&(myWeight>=70)){
        System.out.println("The package is too large and too heavy");
    }
    else 
        if ((mygirth+myLength>=100)){
            System.out.println("The package is too large");
        }
        else 
            if ((myWidth>=70)){
            System.out.print("The package is too heavy");
        }
            else
                System.out.println("The package is fine");
}
```

}

Here is what is displayed in the console:

Enter Dimension 1. 
123

Enter Dimension 2. 
23

Enter Dimension 3. 
14

Enter the weight of the package. 
13

The length of the package is 0

The height of the package is 0

The width of the package is 0

The girth of the package is 0

The package is fine

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the assignments in your CheckMail constructor; i.e. change

```
d1=myLength;
```

to

```
myLength=d1;
```

In Java, the variable being **assigned** is on the left side of the equals, and the **value** to which it is being assigned is on the right.

Currently, your code just re-assigns the parameters to the constructor (which are local to the constructor), using the initial values of the class properties (zero, since in Java, properties with the primitive type `int` are initialized to zero); the class properties themselves are not changed.